How to drag formula to the right in Excel dynamically?
I am trying to drag a formula to the right. How is that possible dynamically, without specifying explicitely the hardcoded cell range?
I can bring the cursor to the specific cell where the formula I want to drag is in, using Find and Offsetting (See screenshot - I can come to the green marked cell). But don't know which cell range it exactly is.
How to drag it by one cell to the right?


rng.Resize(,2).FillRight?

Let's say the reference to the green cell is cell: Dim cell As Range: Set cell = whatever. Then you can use With cell.Offset(1): .Resize(, 2).Formula = .Formula: End With. Please share the code you used to reference the green cell to simplify.

You can also use rng.AutoFill rng.Resize(, 2). rng can also be composed by more than one cell. Even, not formulas. It is able to autofill series, too.

@BigBen it worked! Thanks so much!!!
